# Error processing image dataset\train\image\ff8bf1417c.png: No skimage.transform attribute extract_patches --

Tags: scikit-image, feature-extraction

patches = transform.extract_patches(image, patch_size=(patch_size, patch_size))
patches = patches.reshape(-1, patch_size * patch_size)

this is my code wher e i am getting errorr(Error processing image dataset\train\image\ff532274cd.png: No skimage.transform attribute extract_patches) please help me to solve this

i tried installing the latest version of scikit-image but didnt work